# Adding XML to a table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

- I want a table called TestPack with 3 coulmns - Name, Testcase Number, TestPlan
- TestPlan is a xml file stored in c drive of my computer
- How can I go about creating this table? Note: I want the entire file to be added instead of writing the actual xml code in the 3rd column.

Also, I am fairly new to ASP.NET, c# and Microsoft SQL server, so spare my dumb questions

Comment: How big are your files (X KB, X MB, X GB?) Are you sure you won't need to search in the XML contents? Why don't you want to store it as XML datatype? If you really don't want to store the contents, is storing the file path an option?

Comment: Well, Yes I am sure I will never need to search within the xml, the aim is to access a particular xml file based on the first two columns, and then display that xml file on the UI.

Comment: I would prefer storing the entire xml rather than path.... and the xml files are about 70-100 kb in size

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to create table following this

```
Create Table [MyTable] ( ID int, [myXmlColumn] xml);
```

And then you need to insert data using sqlparameter

```
 public static void InsertXMlDataIntoTableBySQLParameter()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress; 
    Initial Catalog=MorganDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            sqlconnection.Open();

            // create table if not exists 
            string createTableQuery = @"Create Table [MyTable] ( ID int, [myXmlColumn] xml)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTableQuery, sqlconnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           //whateever xml data 
            string xmlData = "<XmlRoot><childNode></childNode></XmlRoot>";

            string insertXmlQuery = @"Insert Into [MyTable] (ID,[myXmlColumn]) Values(1,@myXmlColumn)";

          // Insert XMl Value into Sql Table by SqlParameter
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertXmlQuery, sqlconnection);
            SqlParameter sqlParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myXmlColumn", xmlData);
            sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Xml;
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jagadeesh, but i did not follow it exactly... However, I think the above code does the same thing like the one below. Note: The code written below works well.

'CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML

(

Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\OpenXMLTesting.xml', 'SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML'